# Does Keras BatchNormalization work correctly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

Not really sure whether I'm stupid or not, but shouldn't the values produced by BatchNormalization end up being between -1 and 1? There were already a lot of discussions on Keras BatchNormalization and I couldn't really find what I was looking for. I became suspicious one day and tryed several test scenarios, but none of them produced what I was expecting. I even tried on Google Colab for version problems

EDIT:
So, the question was rather stupid. However, I was more interested in the initial state which is why I set the "lr" so low and was running only one epoch.

btw:

```
tf.__version__
>>> 2.4.1
```

Simple test case:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# a = (np.arange(25, dtype=np.float32)/50).reshape(1, 5, 5, 1)
a = np.arange(25, dtype=np.float32).reshape(1, 5, 5, 1)

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[5,5,1])
initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(1.0, 0.002)
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(inputs)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, 4, strides=2, padding='same', kernel_initializer=initializer, use_bias=False)) # not really necessary
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001, center=True, scale=True))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.000000000001), loss=loss_fn, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(a, a[:, 1:4, 1:4, :], epochs=1, batch_size=1)

print(model(a), 0)
```

```
>>> tf.Tensor(
[[[[ 8.615232]
   [14.495497]
   [ 8.131738]]

  [[26.24201 ]
   [38.98827 ]
   [20.710234]]

  [[17.929565]
   [25.93689 ]
   [13.535995]]]], shape=(1, 3, 3, 1), dtype=float32) 0
```

Comment: No, that is not how z scores work (which is what Batch Norm uses).

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer!! NO!!

You should not expect `BatchNormalization` to give values between -1 to 1.

***Even with Normalised you should not expect values betwen -1 to 1***

But after gamma and beta layer it gets inflated again. The kind of values that you are seeing

Because there are two things that are happening in the BatchNormalisation layer.

1. Normalisation of the Layer using mean and standard $\ddot z$=(z-$\mu$)/$\sigma$
2. Learning of new parameters \gamma and \beta z_delta=\gamma
   *\ddot z+/beta

You can see that Batchnorm layer has 4 parameters 2 untrainable and 2 of them are trainable.

Not able to write properly hence uploading a picture
[image]

Comment: Normalizing the standard deviation to 1 does _not_, at any point, limit values to the range `[-1, 1]`.

Comment: Thanks I have again Updated my answer